# Snowflake Azure External Stage via SAS Token - Key Length Error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Summary:
I'm following this article to try to set up a Snowflake Named External Stage on Azure Blob- Option 2:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html#option-2-generating-a-sas-token

The error I'm getting is "The provided master key has invalid length. It must be either 128 bits, 192 bits, or 256 bits long."

I'm using the Access Key key1 from the storage account, but is that the correct Key?

Details:

On the Azure Side, I have the following:
[image]

I'm using the WebUI instead of the SQL Query and getting the error that the key has invalid length.
URL = azure://[storageaccount_name].blob.core.windows.net/ 
Azure SAS Token = [SAS Token from the Azure Portal field] 
Encryption Master Key = [key1 Key value from the Azure Portal > Storage > [*storage account*] > Access keys > key1 > Key]

[image]

For the Snowflake Stage configuration Encryption Master Key field, I'm using the key1 Key value from the Azure Portal > Storage > [*storage account*] > Access keys > key1 > Key, as that's what was selected when I was generating the SAS:

[image]

Comment: Try following this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/The-provided-master-key-has-invalid-length-It-must-be-either-128-bits-192-bits-or-256-bits-long), even if it's for AWS as principle is the same.

Comment: That's it, thanks @Sergiu

Answer (score 2):

I followed the article here per user @Sergiu suggested:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/The-provided-master-key-has-invalid-length-It-must-be-either-128-bits-192-bits-or-256-bits-long

Comment: Yes, this should be marked as a valid answer